# Bash renaming from path variable

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm doing a "Recycle bin" type script, I have it all done however if a file already exists where I try to restore the file I want it to let the user choose a new name for the file to be restored as, I have the full path the file was deleted from in variable $F1 I just dont know how I go about changing the file name here

```
#!/bin/bash

TRASHCAN ="/home/alihassan/Desktop/Trashcan"
cd $TRASHCAN
F1=$( grep "$1" storage.txt )
if [ -f $F1 ]
    then echo "File already exists at the restore location, please enter a new filename"
    read ANS
    mv "home/alihassan/Desktop/Trashcan/$1" "$F1/$    #ISSUE IS HERE
else
    mv "/home/alihassan/Desktop/Trashcan/$1" "$F1"
fi
```

Comment: `basename "$F1"` is what you need.

Comment: But when I go to move it to its original directory I move to $F1, how to I append the filename to $ANS

Comment: For instance the grep line returns a variable with a full path such as
/home/alihassan/Desktop/pie, I just want the change the end of that path

Comment: Don't forget that the trash might contain five copies of a file named, for example, `makefile` that came from three different source directories.  Do you want to check that the alternative name doesn't exist before you restore to it?

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, you might be after:

```
mv "$TRASHCAN/$1" $(dirname "$F1")/"$ANS"
```

This preserves the original path from `$F1` for all except the last component, and then uses the answer in place of the last component.

Answer (score 0):

Use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to find the original directory:

```bash
read ANS
mv "home/alihassan/Desktop/Trashcan/$1" "${F1%/*}/$ANS"
```

As Jonathan commented about, there is nothing stopping you from "restoring" a file on top of an existing file, overwriting it. You might want to test for the existence of the restore location before performing that `mv`, eg:

```
while read ANS; do
    if [ ! -f "${F1%/*}/$ANS" ]; then
        mv "home/alihassan/Desktop/Trashcan/$1" "${F1%/*}/$ANS"
        break
    else 
        echo "File already exists - please choose another name"
    fi
done
```